# OpenFileDialog.FileFilter strange behaviour

Tags: winforms, openfiledialog, filefilter

In my app I have an OpenFileDialog with a filter like this: `Image Files|*.bmp;*.png;*.gif|All Files|*.*`. On my machine the filter in the dialog is displayed as it should be:

```
Image Files
All Files
```

But on my boss's machine the filter in the dialog looks like this:

```
Image Files (*.bmp, *.png, *.gif)
All Files (*.*)
```

I don't have a single line of code which may change the filter, so I do not understand, why on earth it is displayed this way. What's even more strange is that when I logged into my boss's computer under my account and ran just the same .exe my boss tried it worked like a charm!

Both my and my boss's machine run Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your Windows Explorer settings specify to hide file extensions on your machine, whereas your boss's is configured to show them.

To check this setting:

1. Open **Windows Explorer**
2. Click the **Organize** dropdown
3. Select **Folder and Search Options**
4. Select the **View** tab
5. Look at the list of check boxes under **Advanced settings** and find **Hide extensions for known file types**

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I was at my wits end and blaming Murphy laws.